# Loop through sub elements of different name within a node using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, loops, tags

I'm new to XSLT. I have the following xml and wonder how we can use XSLT to loop through each elements of A to get their value. Also, for each element, if the position mod 3 = 2, get that element value and its next element value. For example,  - because 02 mod 3 = 2, get values 22 and 2.5, and so on.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

```
<A>
 <A01>abc</A01>
 <A02>22</A02>
 <A03>2.5</A03>
 <A04>0</A04>
 <A05>2</A05>
 <A06>1.8</A06>
 <A07>2</A07>
 <A08>3</A08>
 <A09>1.9</A09>
</A>
<A>
 <A01>abb</A01>
 <A02>22</A02>
 <A03>1.5</A03>
 <A04/>
</A>
```

I would like the results to look like below:

```
abc|22|2.5|0
abc|2|1.8|2
abc|3|1.9|
abb|22|1.5|
```

Comment: What do you want your output to look like?

Comment: I want the results to look like this:
abc|22|2.5|0
abc|2|1.8|2
abc|3|19.9|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the output you describe it looks like you want to generate rows whose columns are children 1, n, n+1, n+2 for all n such that n mod 3 = 2.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*/A/*[(position() mod 3) = 2]"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(../*[1],'|', ., '|',
        following-sibling::*[1], '|', following-sibling::*[2],
        '&#10;')"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied on the following XML (your example wrapped in an additional root element to make it well-formed)

```
<root>
<A>
 <A01>abc</A01>
 <A02>22</A02>
 <A03>2.5</A03>
 <A04>0</A04>
 <A05>2</A05>
 <A06>1.8</A06>
 <A07>2</A07>
 <A08>3</A08>
 <A09>1.9</A09>
</A>
<A>
 <A01>abb</A01>
 <A02>22</A02>
 <A03>1.5</A03>
 <A04/>
</A>
</root>
```

this stylesheet produces the correct result

```
abc|22|2.5|0
abc|2|1.8|2
abc|3|1.9|
abb|22|1.5|
```